# Is there a way to collapse functions and sub-routines for Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, asp-classic, vbscript

Is there a way to enabling collapsing of functions and sub-routines for Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2008?  I'm able to manually go through and specify blocks of code as collapsable, but it would save me a lot of time if there was a way to automatically do this.

Otherwise, is there another IDE or text editor that you can think of that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ has a "Function List" plugin:

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189927&package_id=223668

While this doesn't allow you to collapse your Classic ASP functions and sub-routines, it lists them in a side panel and you can click them to jump from function to function.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net) allows you to collapse code. I'm not sure if it collapses on function level, but it sure allows you to collapse whole code blocks and HTML blocks (e.g. you can collapse the "head" or a "div" block, etc).

@coxymla: are you sure mate? I just opened up a HTML page in Notepad++ and I can collapse for example the HEAD without any problems. Maybe I did not explain it clear enough in the above text, but that's because English is not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a good solution for this, unfortunately.

When you open an ASP document, Notepad++ allows you to collapse functions and script blocks, but not HTML elements, even if you set the Language to HTML! (When you open a .htm file in Notepad++, it does allow you to collapse those elements though.)
The VS 2008 text editor is the other way around - HTML elements are fair game but not ASP code itself.

Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

FunctionList plugin does not work  in Windows environment...

NotePad++ will not do code collapse on .asp files...

Answer (score 0):

[Primalscript](http://www.primaltools.com/) does this.  It's mostly very nifty, except it's tending towards bloat which is frustrating.  It's also pricey, but the speed it adds to development probably justifies the cost over time.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code/VS Code is great for classic asp, you need the extension [`Classic ASP` found here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ilich8086.classic-asp)